# MySQL: Issue with CASE statement

Tags: mysql

I have a line of MySQL that I want to use a CASE statement in.  However, I don't think I'm doing it right.  I need to check if a flag is set to a particular value, and then update that flag based on what it is set to.  Here is my MySQL:

`$sql = 'UPDATE table SET flag = CASE WHEN flag = 2 THEN 0 ELSE flag = 3'`

Is that valid SQL?  What I want to do is if the flag is set to a value of 2, set it to 0, else set it to 3.  How do I fix my SQL so it does this?

Comment: Try adding `END` at the end of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is very close, the code will be:

```
UPDATE table 
SET flag = CASE WHEN flag = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 3 END
```

This will update the `flag` column to `0` when the `flag` is equal to `2`, if it is not equal to `2`, then the value will be updated to `3`.